# SUM IF in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Is it possible to SUM on conditions in Power BI?

I have a column that contains the values UK and Italy alongside other columns: employee and hours spent.

I want to make a measure to show total hours spent by an employee in Italy and another to show total hours spent by an employee in UK.

I am having no luck with the DAX language. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. There are two basic approaches to this.

```
CALCULATE(SUM(TableName[Hours]), TableName[Country] = "Italy")
```

or

```
SUMX(FILTER(TableName, TableName[Country] = "Italy"), TableName[Hours])
```

Comment: Perfect. First one works like a charm. I am sure the 2nd does too, but I didn't need to try it.