# How to calculate dynamic Required Measure using TotalMeasure in DAX in which i need to exclude the BLANK() & 0 in NetRevenue for those SKU's?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to calculate the RequiredMeasure column in DAX as shown in the below figure. 
If I remove the Product SKU then the value should not change it should show the total values of RequiredMeasure as 200 only as shown in the below figure.

Please find the below screenshot for clear understanding.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUM IF in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931500/sum-if-in-power-bi)

Answer (score 0):

`SUMX` is the function you need, to iterate over all rows of the table, and calculate an expression:

```
Required Measure = 
    SUMX ( 
        Table1,
        Table1[Net Revenue] * Table1[Total Measure]
    )
```

Worked example file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55255241/